# Issue about preload directives Fonts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fonts, preload

I have a website in Wordpress and i installed a plugin named ARMember just to add paid subscriptions in my site. I am reaching out to seek assistance regarding an issue I am encountering with my website’s login page when accessed from mobile devices.

While the login page functions properly on desktop platforms, I have observed that when attempting to access the same login page from a mobile device, the login form fails to display. Although the page loads without any visible issues, upon inspecting the browser’s console panel, I encountered the following errors:

```
Error: GET https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/armember/fonts/fa-brands-400.eot net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Error: GET https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/armember/fonts/fa-solid-900.eot net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Additionally, I received the following message:
“The resource was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window’s load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally.”

Any assistance or insights you can provide to help rectify these errors and ensure the proper functionality of the login page on mobile devices would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These eot files are in fact missing. As a workaround you may try to add them manually. What's really strange: these are fonts for internet explorer <9 - so nay modern browser should ignore them completely in favor of woff2 or woff. If the plugin adds a link/preload element to the header loading this obsolete font format it should be removed. So you should report this as a bug